# safari 10 flexbox img overlap and parent size issues. bootstrap 4 cards

Tags: safari, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a grid layout that works in all browsers I need except Safari 10. The images and text below should fit inside the card & btn setup but they all crowd together.

The problem in an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOKMk.png)

Correct view in IE11 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Varrk.jpg)

Here is a [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/uyEOFuUjJl)

- I attempted to add flex:1; in a class to one of the parents and that fixed it but then it causes the same problem in IE11.

css

```
 .img-fluid {
width: 100%;
}

.tall {
padding: .6em 1rem 0 1rem;
}

.wide {
padding-top: .7em;
}
```

html

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 pb-3 px-2 ">
                <div class="card h-100 border border-secondary h-100 text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="btn  h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <div>
                            <img src="http://picsum.photos/300/200" class="img-fluid wide">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <p class=" text-dark">Wide Img Btn<br> <span class="text-warning d-block d-md-none">Invisible save for phones Extended captions will wrap blah blah blah</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Usually browser caching issue in Safari. Clear the cache.

Comment: I am using an online service -lambdatest.com- that starts each session with a fresh browser.  I dont have a mac. Did you test in Safari 10?

Comment: Well, then you have your answer right there...

Comment: What does that mean? I dont know if you are saying the remote server is not clearing cache, you dont like lambdatest, I should own a mac?

Comment: I tried this on a different service and the result is the same, its not browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like safari10 has a weird logic in calculating the height when you set `height: 100%;` (`h-100` class) to the anchor tag.

I believe, the only option to make it work in safari10 is remove it and make use of `justify-content: center;` along with a `min-height` to the `.card`.

For the `<p class=" text-dark">` we need to make it `position: absolute;` and use `bottom: 0;` to make it stick to the bottom of the container.

[BOOTPLY](https://www.bootply.com/YjChpVx5Nr)

Tested in Safari10, IE11 and latest versions of all browsers. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I looked at the bootply, and thank you for the effort!  It does some weird things to the layout when the screen is narrow.  There is a lot of extra space  at the top of the cards on large screens and the captions overlap the pictures on phones.